# Constant lookup

Tags: ruby

#### Scenario #1:

In the example below, `puts Post::User.foo` line prints `foo`. In other words `Post::User` returns a global `User` constant.

```
class User
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
end

class Post
  puts Post::User.foo
end
# => warning: toplevel constant User referenced by Post::User
# => foo
```

#### Scenario #2:

This second example raises an error because no constant is found.

```
module User
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
end

module Post
  puts Post::User.foo
end
# => uninitialized constant Post::User (NameError)
```

The result of scenario #2 is more intuitive. Why is the constant found in scenario #1? If `User` constant is returned in scenario #1, why isn't that happening in scenario #2? In scenario #2, `Post` is a module, so in that case, constant should be searched in `Object.ancestors`, which should also return `User` constant, but this is not happening.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the fact that in the case of the module `Post.ancestors` doesn’t include `Object`, but with the class it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour is caused by the lookup happening inside a module, instead of in a class. (the fact that you are looking up a module inside the module and a class inside the class is irrelevant).

```
module M
  def self.foo; "moo" end
end

class C
  def self.foo; "coo" end
end

class A
  A::M.foo rescue puts $! # warning: toplevel constant M referenced by A::M
  A::C.foo rescue puts $! # warning: toplevel constant M referenced by A::M
end

module B
  B::M.foo rescue puts $! # error: uninitialized constant B::M
  B::C.foo rescue puts $! # error: uninitialized constant B::C
end
```

If you look at the C code, both of these call into [rb_const_get_0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/variable.c#L1868) with exclude=true, recurse=true, visibility=true.

In the case of A::M, this looks up:

```
tmp = A
tmp::M  # (doesn't exist)
tmp = tmp.super # (tmp = Object) 
tmp::M  # (exists, but warns).
```

In the case of B::M, this looks up:

```
tmp = B
tmp::M # (doesn't exist)
tmp = tmp.super # (modules have no super so lookup stops here)
```

Because exclude is true, the usual edge case for modules jumping to (`tmp = Object`) is skipped. This means that `B::M` behaves differently to `module B; M; end`, which is arguably an inconsistency in ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and the answer. I also tweeted to Pat Shaughnessy and he confirmed this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, please consider that all **top-level** constants are defined in class `Object`, because Ruby is an object-oriented language and there can not be a variable or constant that does not belong to some class:

```
class A; end
module B; end

A == Object::A # => true 
B == Object::B # => true
```

Second, class `Object` is by default an **ancestor** of any class, but not of a module:

```
class A; puts ancestors; end # => [A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
module B; puts ancestors; end # => []
```

At the same time, there's no `Object` in neither of`Module.nesting`:

```
class A; puts Module.nesting; end # => [A]
module B; puts Module.nesting; end # => [B]
```

Then, chapter 7.9 of [the Matz book mentioned above](http://amzn.com/0596516177) says that Ruby searches for any constant in `Module.nesting` and then in `ancestors`.

Therefore, in your example, it finds the constant `User` for class `Post`, because Ruby defines **top-level** constant `User` in class `Object` (as `Object::User`). And `Object` is an **ancestor** of `Post`:

```
Object::User == Post::User # => true
```

But there is no `Object` in `ancestors` or `Module.nesting` of your module `Post`. The constant `Post` is defined in class `Object` as `Object::Post` but it does not derive from `Object` because `module Post` **is not an object**. Therefore, it does not resolve constant `User` in **module** `Post` through it's `ancestors`.

At the same time, it will work if you keep `User` to be a `module` and turn `Post` into a class:

```
module User
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
end

class Post
  puts Post::User.foo
end

# => foo
```

That's because `class Post` can resolve any constant inside it's superclass `Object` and all **top-level** constants are defined in `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

> **  `class` keyword in ruby is actually a method name which accepts Constant and defines a class for it

In case of scenario 1, when  `puts Post::User.foo` gets invoked. Ruby looks whether it has a class `Post::User` defined (Ruby searches it as a constant, because that's what it is). Once it finds it,  foo method gets called.

But in scenario 2 you have defined it inside modules since when `puts Post::User.foo` gets invoked and there exist no such class as `Post::User`. Search fails and you get the obvious error message.

You may refer **Class Names Are Constants** Section in  [this](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/classes.html)  link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i think is in the difference of <del>inheritance level of Class and Module ([ascii image](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html)). In fact Class object is inherited from Module object.</del> ancestors that are looked up.

```
module A; end
p A.ancestors   #=> [A]

class B; end
p B.ancestors   #=> [B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

That means if lookup algorithm step in `module A`, it can not step out.

So in case of `module Post` lookup algorithm of `Post::User` is something like

- find const `Post` (found `module Post`)
- find const `User` in `module Post` (not found, go for ancestors of `Post`)
- dead-end - error

and in case of `class Post`

- find const `Post` (found `class Post`)
- find const `User` in `class Post` (not found, go for ancestors of `Post`)
- find const `User` (found `class User` with warning)

That's why you can chain classes in one level of namespace and ruby will still find them. If you try

```
class User
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
end

class A1; end

class A2; end

class Foo
  p Foo::A1::A2::User.foo
end
#... many of warnings
#> "foo"
```

is still good.
And

```
class User
  def self.foo
    "foo1"
  end
end

class A1; end

module A2; end

class Foo
  p Foo::A1::A2::User.foo
end
#>.. some warnings
#> uninitialized constant A2::User (NameError)
```

because lookup algorithm steps in module and got trapped.

**TL;DR**

```
class User
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
end

class Post1
  Post1.tap{|s| p s.ancestors}::User.foo #=> [Post1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
end
# ok

module Post2
  Post2.tap{|s| p s.ancestors}::User.foo #=> [Post2]
end
# error
```

**Updated**

In this situation the place at what Post::User.foo was called does not play much role. It could be also outside of class/module and the behaviour will be the same.

```
module ModuleA; end
class ClassB;  end
class ClassC;  end

class E;  ModuleA::ClassC; end   # error
module F; ClassB::ClassC;  end   # ok

ClassB::ClassC    # ok
ClassB::ModuleA   # ok
ModuleA::ClassB   # error
```

And as you pointed out

> Sure, ancestors for a module or class differ, but in the case of
>   module, the additional constant lookup in Object.ancestors happens.

it happens **only** at moment of "initial" lookup. It means that in case of

```
module Post; Post::User.foo; end
```

const `Post` will firstly be looked in (here I can mistake something) `Post.ancestors` and because there are no `Post::Post`, continue to find in `Object.ancestors` (then it will go with algorithm that i described at top).

**Summing up**, the context at what you called const matter only for first (most left) const lookup. And then only what object is left considered.

```
A::B::C
A        # consider context
 ::B     # consider only A
    ::C  # consider only B
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort in providing detailed answer, but I think this is not correct. Sure, ancestors for a module or class differ, but in the case of module, the additional constant lookup in `Object.ancestors` happens. This "exception" for module constant lookup has been documented [here](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html) and also in [this book](http://amzn.com/0596516177), chapter 7.9 "Constant lookup" (page 261). I think this example proves modules do not perform a "trap" `module Foo; Integer; end`. `Integer` constant will be found in top-level namespace.

Comment: @BrunoSutic you misunderstood me a bit. Lookup got trapped not because it was called from module context, but because it got in `module Post` when doing lookup. So example should be `module Foo; Foo::Integer; end` that will raise error.